# ERROR: InstallAnywhere 2014 (SP1 Premier) Incomplete installation

Tags: license-key, installanywhere

InstallAnywhere provides an executable(Build.exe) which runs the installer build process from the command-line.

I was able to use this file without any problems until i tried to update the JRE
provided with the InstallAnywhere application. That's what i did:

1. I used Build.exe to build my installer
2. I noticed I had some annoying java related warnings during the process(console output)
3. After a little research I came across a solution that offered to update the included JRE (Ver. 1.7) in the InstallAnywhere root folder.
4. I replaced the JRE with a more recent version (1.8)

Since then I get the following error only when Build.exe is used. The InstallAnywhere GUI works just fine.

The error:

```
This is an incomplete installation of InstallAnywhere 2014 SP1 Evaluation.
```

Because of this error I can't use Build.exe anymore even though
**I'm using a licensed version of InstallAnywhere 2014 Premier.**

This error message won't go away no matter what I do, I tried to:

1. restore the original JRE
2. Reinstall InstallAnywhere
3. Supplying the license again (License server)

What's causing this error? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InstallAnywhere saves some hidden files in the user folder. 
These files are not deleted during the uninstall process.

Look for this folder:

```
C:\Users\[User_Name]\InstallAnywhere\165\Premier
```

The sub-folders **\165\premier** are probably different from user to user depands on the version & license.

There you can find the folder **preferences**, make a copy of this folder & delete it. After this you can launch InstallAnywhere & enter your license information again.